# Why use observer with rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, websocket, observers, reactivex

I am currently developing a small app that basically copies whatsapp's functionality, beeing a simple chat.

For that I use websockets and I've stumbled upon several tutorials and stackoverflow posts that use this kind of code for the websocket, which I then used for my project.

```js
private create(url) {
    const websocket = new WebSocket(url);
    const observable: Observable<MessageEvent> = Observable.create(
      (observerInLambda: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
        websocket.onmessage = observerInLambda.next.bind(observerInLambda);
        websocket.onerror = observerInLambda.error.bind(observerInLambda);
        websocket.onclose = observerInLambda.complete.bind(observerInLambda);
        return websocket.close.bind(websocket); // When unsubbing from the observable the websocket is closed
      }
    );
    const observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (websocket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          websocket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      },
      error: (err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log("complete");
      }
    };

    return Subject.create(observer, observable);
}
```

This works mostly fine, appart from the disconnecting on unsubscribe, but thats not my question. I get that i have to use some sort of callback/event style code like `websocket.onmessage = (data:Object) => doStuff(data);` to read from the websocket, but what confuses me why I would have to use a an observer, whose `.next` function i call, which in turn calls `websocket.send`. Why not simply call `websocket.send` instead, which isn't a asynchronous function anyway...

To me it seems that the whole pattern including the subject is a bit overkill for what I am doing? Am I getting something wrong, or is simply not useful in my case?

Comment: for features really. how would you merge the incoming events from 2 sockets? how would you do retries on failure? debounce? the rx api is very powerfull. :)

Comment: also, any answers to this question are just going to be opinion based. it really depends on your needs. I'll vote to close the question because of that. :)

Comment: Don't write more code than you need. That code is ugly. Annotating the types of locals is bad style

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why would that be? otherwise I'll have any types everywhere and i have to revisit the code again to find out the purposed types?

Comment: @LukasKurz omit the types and they will be inferred. What made you think and an annotation was required?